# SPARQL count number of relations at once

Tags: sparql

Is it possible to get, in a single query, a count of the number of multiple relations? e.g.

```
SELECT (COUNT(?friendid) as ?friends) (COUNT(?cousinid) as ?cousins)  (COUNT(?sonid) as ?sons)
WHERE
{
  ex:person1 ex:friendOf ?friendid .
  ex:person1 ex:cousinOf ?cousinid .
  ex:person1 ex:fatherOf ?sonid .
}
```

If a complex query with multiple queries is needed, is this -in theory, of course- supposed to be faster than executing different SELECTs?

Comment: I don't think that your query works. It will return the same number for each relation I guess.

Comment: Yes, that is what is happening... and the reason of my question : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following query retrieves ALL the predicates and their numbers:

```
SELECT ?p (COUNT(?p) as ?pCount) WHERE { ex:person1 ?p ?o} GROUP BY ?p
```

This one restricts the predicates (AKSW's suggestion):

```
SELECT ?p (COUNT(?p) as ?pCount) WHERE { ex:person1 ?p ?o. VALUES (?p) {(:p1)}} GROUP BY ?p
```

Here is an example:

```
SELECT ?p (COUNT(?p) as ?pCount) WHERE
{
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Museums_in_Italy> ?p ?o .
  VALUES (?p) {(skos:altLabel) (owl:sameAs)}
}
GROUP BY ?p
```

And here are the results:

[Results](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT+%3Fp+%28COUNT%28%3Fp%29+as+%3FpCount%29+WHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCategory%3AMuseums_in_Italy%3E+%3Fp+%3Fo+.%0D%0A++VALUES+%28%3Fp%29+%7B%28skos%3AaltLabel%29+%28owl%3AsameAs%29%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AGROUP+BY+%3Fp)

Comment: In addition, if he/she wants to restrict the properties, then `VALUES ?p (:p1 :p2 ...)` can be used

Comment: One thing - if I use `VALUES ?p (:p1 :p2...)` and there is no :p1 for example, I always get a count of "1" instead of "0" as one would expect. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think you are making a mistake! I edited my answer according to AKSW's suggestion and it works! I think when you have a problem you can always try first on the endpoint so that you can see where the problem is!

Comment: Ok, I found the error with your help. I was using OPTIONAL { <..> ?p ?o}  OPTIONAL {?o ?p <...>} because I need to get both when the id is a subject and an object. However this makes VALUE to always return at least one instance.... No sure there is an easy fix for this or I will have to run two different queries